# Dynamically Logging source filename in python without passing filename as a parameter everytime

Tags: python, logging, filenames

I'm trying to create a Logger which dynamically logs the filename, function_name and line number from where the logger is triggered.

I tried the following code.

**log.py**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def log_message(message):
    logger.info(message)
```

**check.py**

```
from log import log_message

def A():
    log_message("Error occurred")
A()
```

when I run check.py, it gives the output as..

```
[log.py:8 -          log_message() ] Error occurred
```

But I want it like,

```
[check.py:4 -          A() ] Error occurred
```

Is there any way to attain this dynamically without passing the filename everytime as a parameter like this.

```
logger.info(file_name=__name__, function_name=function_name)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the stacklevel in `logger.info`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def log_message(message):
    logger.info(message, stacklevel=2)


def test():
    log_message("Hi")


test()
```

Output:

```
[scratch_1.py:20 -                 test() ] Hi
```